# django rest framework recursive models endpoints structure

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have three models like this (Simplified).

```py
class Locker(CoreModel):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    topic = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('topic'),
        help_text=_("locker description"),
        null=True,
        max_length=1024
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('name'),
        help_text=_("locker name"),
        max_length=100,
        validators=(
            MinLengthValidator(2),
        )
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='owned_locker_set',
        verbose_name=_('owner'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


class Folder(CoreModel):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('name'),
        help_text=_('name of the folder'),
        max_length=256
    )
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        to='self',
        verbose_name=_('parent'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    locker = models.ForeignKey(
        to='lockers.Locker',
        verbose_name=_('locker'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False
    )


class Upload(CoreModel):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('name'),
        help_text=_("upload name"),
        max_length=100,
        validators=(
            MinLengthValidator(2),
        )
    )
    locker = models.ForeignKey(
        to='lockers.Locker',
        verbose_name=_('locker'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False
    )
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        to='lockers.Folder',
        verbose_name=_('folder'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    file = PrivateFileField(
        verbose_name=_('file'),
        help_text=_("raw file"),
        upload_to='uploads/',
        storage=private_storage
    )
```

as you can see, the structure is recursive.
Ideally, from the frontend, I would want to make a single request to return all the files and folders the
locker has at the root level (parent is None). Then, I would also like to make requests to get all the files and folders inside of a specified folder ( when the user opens a folder at the frontend).

I am using Django Rest Framework right now.
However, I cannot think of a way to achieve this because I would have to serialize two models into one view (I also want support for pagination). How can this be implemented in the simplest way?

Can someone please help me?
Thanks a lot in advance!

relevant github discussion is [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/discussions/7920).

**Edit**
I can imagine the endpoints structure to be like this.

```py
# lists all files and folders in the locker.
path('lockers/<int:locker_id>/metadata/')
# lists all files and folders in the folder with the given pk.
path('lockers/<int:locker_id>/folders/<int:pk>/metadata/'),
# create an upload.
path('lockers/<int:locker_id>/uploads/')
# create and list the folders available.
path('lockers/<int:locker_id>/folders/'),
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with extra action in DRF https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing. And you can define serializers for each actions with get_serializer_class function in viewsets

Comment: by implementing this solution I would have to make two requests everytime to retrieve both the folders and the files, which is not something I want.